# Solspace Freeform : error notice in control panel

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, ee3

I've just installed the free version of Solspace Freeform 5.1.1 in ExpressionEngine 3.4.5. When I go to *Add-On Manager > Freeform > Forms* and go to edit my form I see this notification:

[image: screen grab of Solspace Freeform error]

...this appears to be preventing me from editing the form fields.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to fix this error please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with Freeform 5.1.1 (and earlier) and EE 3.4.5+. This issue has since been fixed in Freeform [5.1.2](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/changelog/#v5-1-2) :)

Comment: Ok, many thanks for letting me know. I'll email you regarding the patched version. Merry Christmas to you!